# pandas create a one row dataframe from nested dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I know the "create pandas dataframe from nested dict" has a lot of entries here but I'm not found the answer that applies to my problem:

I have a dict like this:

```
{'id': 1,
 'creator_user_id': {'id': 12170254,
  'name': 'Nicolas',
  'email': 'some_mail@some_email_provider.com',
  'has_pic': 0,
  'pic_hash': None,
  'active_flag': True,
  'value': 12170254}....,
```

and after reading with pandas look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict,orient='index')
print(df)

id                                                                        1
creator_user_id           {'id': 12170254, 'name': 'Nicolas', 'email': '...
user_id                   {'id': 12264469, 'name': 'Daniela Giraldo G', ...
person_id                 {'active_flag': True, 'name': 'Cristina Cardoz...
org_id                    {'name': 'Cristina Cardozo', 'people_count': 1...
stage_id                                                                  2
title                                                      Cristina Cardozo
```

I would like to create a one-row dataframe where, for example, the nested  `creator_user_id` column results in several columns that I after can name: `creator_user_id_id, creator_user_id_name,` etc.

thank you for your time!

Comment: pls post the complete dictionary or some more data of it, it will be easy to debug! based on your expected output, this is use case where need to write some code that will flat out the dictionary before feeding it to pandas.

Comment: it looks like nested dictionaries have different keys - so it will make problem.

Comment: maybe you should first convert every nested dict to DataFrame - `from_dict(data['creator_user_id'], ...)` - and later join/merge/conatenate all of them. But if every nested dictionary have different keys then you get empty places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you want one row,  just use `json_normalize()`

```
pd.json_normalize({'id': 1,
 'creator_user_id': {'id': 12170254,
  'name': 'Nicolas',
  'email': 'some_mail@some_email_provider.com',
  'has_pic': 0,
  'pic_hash': None,
  'active_flag': True,
  'value': 12170254}})
```